# Angular JS redirect after login

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I have two controllers on the same page, one for login controller and the other controller. The first controller is bound to the path "/" and the second is bound to the path "/mypath".
If the user is not logged in, then he can't access to the latter. He can log in through the first controller.

The problem is that, when the user log in, the page will routed to the path "/". How to prevent this? I want the page to remain at current path.
This is what I have tried. The `$locationChangeStart` event :

```
mstdapp.run(["$rootScope", function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, newUrl, oldUrl){
        $rootScope.returnUrl = newUrl;
        console.log("new url in run is :");
        console.log(newUrl);        
    });
 }]);
```

Then, in the login controller :

```
$scope.login = function(){          
            authService.Authenticate($scope.user)
            .then(function(res){                
                $scope.user.displayname = res.data.name;
                $scope.isLoggedIn = authService.isAuthenticated();              
                console.log($rootScope.returnUrl);
            }, function(res){
                alert(res.data.error_description);
                console.log($rootScope.returnUrl);
            });           

};
```

The `$rootScope.returnUrl` points to the "/" path.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: I tried `$locationChangeStart` event to capture the current URL and pass in the `$rootScope` to the login controller. Then, after login success, I then `$location.path(previousURL)` to second controller. But, it is not working as expected.

Comment: can you jsfiidle it?

Comment: Not quite used to jsfiddle. But, added my code. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It is because the login button is actually an `<a>` with  `href="#"`. That is why the page is redirected to root path. Removing the `href` solves my problem.